# JavaScript element.classList.add("fa fa-hand-rock-o") Error: "String contains an invalid character"

Tags: javascript, font-awesome

I'm trying to add a class to 
`<span id="sp1">` using:

```
document.getElementById("sp1").classList.add("fa fa-hand-rock-o");
```

But it is showing error:

> String contains an invalid character

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`fa fa-hand-rock-o` can not be a single class because class names can not have space(s).

Here I assume you are trying to add two different classes. When adding multiple classes by using `classList.add()` specify all the classes as individual comma separated string like:

`.add("fa", "fa-hand-rock-o")`

**Code Example:**

```js
document.getElementById("sp1").classList.add("fa","fa-hand-rock-o");

console.log(document.getElementById("sp1"));
```

```html
<span id="sp1">Test Container</span >
```

Comment: Thanks @Mamun, this answer helped me add font-awesome class using "class1", "class2" trick.

Answer (score 1):

The white space between two class name is creating the issue.If need to add multiple class separate them by a comma and put each of them inside a quote

```js
document.getElementById("sp1").classList.add("fa", "fa-hand-rock-o")
```

```css
.fa {
  color: red;
}

.fa-hand-rock-o {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<li id="sp1"> Test Text </li>
```