# How to add class to element in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, dom

I do following statement to add 'hold-transition login-page' class to the `<body id='the_body'>` element

```
import React, { Component,useEffect } from 'react';
export default class Login extends React.Component {
componentDidMount() {
document.getElementById("the_body").classList.add('hold-transition login-page')
}
render() {
return(
<div className="login-box">
...some html script
</div>
)
}
```

but I get this error

```
InvalidCharacterError: String contains an invalid character
componentDidMount

I am already make simple javcript code inside  `componentDidMount()`

componentDidMount(){
 alert('test javascript inside jsx');
}
```

it is running well. but why my dom statement is error?. finaly I hope you to fix my problem, thank you

Comment: Duplicate [JavaScript element.classList.add("fa fa-hand-rock-o") Error: "String contains an invalid character"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49348858/javascript-element-classlist-addfa-fa-hand-rock-o-error-string-contains-an) although you really shouldn't manipulate DOM directly in React.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how people modify classes with React but the problem in your example is that "hold-transition login-page" is not a valid class name.

If you want to add multiple class names you should try

```
classList.add("hold-transition", "login-page")
```

Comment: thank you bro, I realize my mistake now
I clone my dom statement 
1.add class hold-transition
2.add class login-page
classList.add("hold-transition")
classList.add("login-page")

its' work